# Llenar TextBox con TextMode=Date de Asp.Net desde Date SQL

Tags: html, c#, html5, sql-server, asp.net

Quisiera saber como puedo llenar un textbox de tipo "Date" con una fecha obtenida desde una tabla de SQL Server

Actualmente lo tengo así

```
 txtFecha.Text = (((DateTime)firstTable.Rows[0]["FechaCredito"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).ToString();
```

Pero a la hora de verlo desde el formulario, me muestra como si no se hubiese cargado nada, en vez de llenarlo, de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo agradecido de antemano

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: acá está la respuesta, acabo de pasar por lo mismo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745661/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-textmode-date-asp-net-c-sharp/33212980#33212980 .

Answer (score 0):

Una solución puede ser convertir la consulta en un objeto de tipo DateTime y luego asignarselo al textBox dandole formato de fecha:

```
  Dim conn As New SqlConnection()
    conn = New SqlConnection(conexion)
    conn.Open()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE DATO = @DATO"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATO", (txtDato.Text))
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.Read() Then
        Dim dt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.Item("FechaCredito").ToString())
        txtFecha.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt)
    End If
```

No sé si sea la mejor manera, pero a mi me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciono aun cuando la consulta viene de LinQ

```
txtFecha.Text = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", dt)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Format(vld_FechaHora, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm")
```

El formato a mi me funcionó `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`